# Django Foreign Key To Any Subclass of Abstract Model

Tags: python, django, generic-foreign-key

I have an abstract Django model with two concrete implementations. E.g.

```py
class Animal(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField("name", max_length=100)

    class Meta:
        abstract = True


class Dog(Animal):
    ...


class Cat(Animal):
   ...
```

And then I want to create a generic foreign key that points to a Dog or a Cat. From the documentation about [GenericForeignKeys](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/ref/contrib/contenttypes/#django.contrib.contenttypes.generic.GenericForeignKey) I know that I can do something like

```py
from django.contrib.contenttypes.fields import GenericForeignKey
from django.contrib.contenttypes.models import ContentType
from django.db import models

class Appointment(models.Model):
    
    content_type = models.ForeignKey(ContentType, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    object_id = models.PositiveIntegerField()
    patient = GenericForeignKey("content_type", "object_id")
```

But

1. I have to do this for every model that can point to a `Dog` or a `Cat`.
2. It doesn't enforce that the foreign key actual points to an `Animal`.

Is there a way to set up my `Animal` model such that in the `Appointment` model I can just do

```py
class Apointment(models.Model):
   patient = GenericRelation(Animal)
```

Answer (score 1):

To address your requirement of creating a foreign key in Django that points specifically to subclasses of an abstract `Animal` model (like Dog or Cat in your case), without having to repeat the setup for every model and ensuring that the foreign key indeed points to an Animal subclass, you can create a custom `Model` field.
This custom field for example `AnimalGenericForeignKey`, would be a specialized version of Django's `GenericForeignKey`.

This custom field would internally use the mechanisms of `GenericForeignKey` but with added logic to ensure the relationship is only with `Animal` subclasses.
You need to define `AnimalGenericForeignKey` once and then use it in any model where you need to reference an `Animal` subclass. When you declare this field in a model like `Appointment`, it would manage the relationship and enforce that the linked object is a `Dog` or a `Cat`, or any other subclass of `Animal` class you have.

Keep your `Animal`, `Dog`, `Cat` model class as it is.

As said earlier create a new Custom Field I name it as `AnimalGenericForeignKey`:

```
from django.contrib.contenttypes.fields import GenericForeignKey
from django.core.exceptions import ValidationError

class AnimalGenericForeignKey(GenericForeignKey):
    def validate(self, value, model_instance):
        super().validate(value, model_instance)
        if not issubclass(value.__class__, Animal):
            raise ValidationError("This field must be set to an Animal subclass instance.")
```

This custom field will extend Django's `GenericForeignKey` and include validation to ensure it only points to an `Animal` subclass.

Use this custom fields in anywhere you want in your case let's use this in `Appointment` model class.

```
from django.contrib.contenttypes.models import ContentType
class Appointment(models.Model):
    content_type = models.ForeignKey(ContentType, on_delete=models.CASCADE, limit_choices_to={'model__in': ('dog', 'cat')})
    object_id = models.PositiveIntegerField()
    patient = AnimalGenericForeignKey('content_type', 'object_id')

    #Do what you need.....
```

Ref. [Model ForeignKey limit choices](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/5.0/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.ForeignKey.limit_choices_to)

I hope this will help. In case any questions feel free to ask in comment.